# Error al ejecutar app de flutter para verla en el emulador o en el móvil

Tags: flutter, vscode

Estoy recién empezando en flutter, pero me sale un error que no puedo solucionar.

Al ejecutar o depurar la app me sale este error, trate de buscar y resolverlo, pero lamentablemente no pude. Todo esto es en Vs code

Si de casualidad hubiera alguna solución, por favor me la podría dar se lo agradecería muchísimo, gracias!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a SOes, tu pregunta quedaria mejor poniendo el mensaje de error en formato texto y agrega lo que has intentado hasta el momento para que los usuarios puedan ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola igualmente!! Disculpe por el error, la verdad que es mi primera pregunta entonces estaba medio perdido, pero gracias!! Tratare de actualizarla.